# layout_gravity in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-gravity

This is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nazajGumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/roaming_backbtn" >
        </Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/roaming_homebtn" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:prompt="@string/roaming_spinnerPrompt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Random text"
        android:textColor="#ffffcc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/testBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="test" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

The positioning of ImageView and TextView in LinearLayout2 and positiong of buttons in LinearLayout3 is not working (using layout gravity).

What am i missing here?

Comment: What do you mean not working? Like they are both left aligned...?

Comment: Yes they are both left aligned.

Comment: if you have the linearlayout orientation set to 'horizontal', gravity left or right does not work. Setting it to vertical wil make this possible. I am just not sure what you are trying to accomplish here...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That's not the way in which `android:layout_gravity` works. Both, `left` and `center_horizontal` parameters work only when the `android:orientation` is `vertical`. To achieve what you want, you better use `RelativeLayout`:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView   
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

        <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tnx. Is this a bug or a rule that you can't use left/center horizontal in horizontal orientation of linear layout?

Comment: It's not a bug. Just a feature.

Comment: I don't think you need `android:orientation` attribute in `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer by @Cristian the same thing can also be done using Linear Layout by extensive use of the attributes - "weight" and "weight_sum" (although a more tedious approach) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="5"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent_linear_layout">

    <!-- Sub #1 Linear Layout #1 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/sub_1_linear_layout_1">

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/stack_overflow"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_2">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #3 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/stack_overflow"
                android:textColor="#111111"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #4 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_4">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #5 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_5">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Sub #1 Linear Layout #2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="5"
        android:id="@+id/sub_1_linear_layout_2">

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_1_2">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #2 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_2_2">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #3 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_3_2">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/back"
                android:id="@+id/back_button"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #4 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_4_2">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Sub #2 Linear Layout #5 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/sub_2_linear_layout_5_2">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/home"
                android:id="@+id/home_button"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Sub #1 Linear Layout #3 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/sub_1_linear_layout_3">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:prompt="@string/random_prompt"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Sub #1 Linear Layout #4 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/sub_1_linear_layout_4">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:text="@string/random_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Sub #1 Linear Layout #5 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/sub_1_linear_layout_5">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#111111"
            android:text="@string/test_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: Since API level 8 "fill_parent" has been deprecated and "match_parent" is used instead. See - [What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Answer (score -21):

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
```

should be (dp not dip)

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
```

Comment: They are equivalent actually, and that won't solve the problem.

Comment: In fact it's been reported anecdotally that dp sometimes fails to work where dip works, despite documentation stating they are the same.