# What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a little confused about two XML properties: `match_parent` and `fill_parent`. It seems that both are the same. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: if you feel free https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams

Answer (score 1273, accepted):

They're the same thing (in API Level 8+). Use `match_parent`.

> FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)
>
> ...
>
> `fill_parent`: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: if I write app for both 1.6 and 2.2, I will use fill_parent for compatibility, is it right?

Comment: There must be some differences right? Otherwise why Google deprecated it and renamed the new one?

Comment: @Halim No, there is **no differece**: Both are defined as constant `-1`.
I you feel better about it, I don't get the impovement in that either... :-)

Comment: @arpy - Actually, there has to be some internal differences. There's an error that pops up on older (post-API 8 but pre ICS) that can appear when using MATCH_PARENT as a constant instead of FILL_PARENT when creating a view programatically. Error: "Can't get the viewWidth"

Comment: @jlovison No, there are no differences. Both are `-1`. You get the error because the older platform does not know about the new name of the very same constant.

Comment: It is so weird that Android Studio still puts "fill_parent" in all default template created layouts! I know they are the same, but I keep coming back to this SO question every year to make sure no one has discovered that there really is a difference. Can the Google/Android-team please change the default value from "fill_parent" to "match_parent"? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 260):

Google changed the name to avoid confusion.

Problem with the old name `fill parent` was that it implies its affecting the dimensions of the parent, while `match parent` better describes the resulting behavior - match the dimension with the parent.

Both constants resolve to `-1` in the end, and so result in the identical behavior in the app.  Ironically enough, this name change made to clarify things seems to have added confusion rather than eliminating it.

Comment: ...except with RelativeLayout's child with width=match_parent and, say, leftOf another. It does not match its parent's dimension, it fills what remains in it. That serves only to CAUSE confusion.

Comment: As FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding isn't that the interior space rather than the outer dimensions? Now I'm even more confused!

Comment: @bnieland I have removed the references to inner and outer dimensions as they don't agree with the google documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT although I can see a similar (unsubstantiated) quote at http://sevennet.org/2014/11/22/how-to-what-is-the-difference-between-match_parent-and-fill_parent/ which is where you might have got your information from.

Answer (score 31):

Functionally no difference, Google just changed the name from fill_parent to match_parent, from API level 8 (Android 2.2). FILL_PARENT is still available for compatibility reason.

`LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` and `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` both have value -1. Not sure what tempted google to change from Fill Parent to Match Parent :)

Since most of the `phones are >= Android 2.2` .. you should use Match Parent for future compatibility... not sure when they will discontinue the older Fill Parent constant!

Answer (score 11):

`FILL_PARENT` is deprecated in API level 8 and `MATCH_PARENT`use higherlevel API

Answer (score 10):

**match_parent**  is used in place of **fill_parent** and sets it to go as far as the parent goes. Just use **match_parent** and forget about **fill_parent**. I completely ditched **fill_parent** and everything is perfect as usual.

Check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) for more.

Answer (score 7):

Both have similar functionality only difference is that fill_parent is used up to API level 8 and match_parent is used after API level 8 or higher level.

Answer (score 7):

When you set layout `width` and `height`  as `match_parent` in `XML` property, it will occupy the complete area that the parent view has, i.e. it will be as big as the parent.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#f9b0b0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0f9dc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hare parent is red and child is green. Child occupy all area. Because it's `width` and `height`  are `match_parent`.

[image]

Note : If parent is applied a padding then that space would not be included.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#f9b0b0"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b0f9dc"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

So TextView hight = 300dp(parent hight) - (20(paddingTop)+10(paddingBottom))
= (300 - 30) dp
= 270 dp

### fill_parent Vs match_parent

`fill_parent` is previous name of `match_parent`

For API Level 8 and higher `fill_parent` renamed as `match_parent` and `fill_parent` is deprecated now.

So `fill_parent` and `match_parent` are same.

### API Documentation for fill_parent

The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by {@code match_parent}.

Answer (score 6):

**Just to give it a name closer to it's actual action**. `"fill_parent"` does not fill the remaining space as the name would imply (for that you use the weight attribute). Instead, it takes up as much space as its layout parent. That's why the new name is `"match_parent"`

Comment: I do not understand people's logic when they state this. Parent has padding. Or child is leftOf another. Is the child matching it? No. is it filling the remaining space? Here in what is apparently Bizzarro World, we answer: yes.

Comment: @kaay I totally agree the new name is worse than the old one. But what Google says goes.

Answer (score 4):

`match_parent`  and `fill_parent`  are same property, used to define width or height of a view in full screen horizontally or vertically.

These properties are used in android xml files like this.

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

or

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

`fill_parent` was used in previous versions, but now it has been deprecated and replaced by `match_parent`.
I hope it'll help you.

Answer (score 4):

fill_parent: The view should be as big as its parent.

now this content fill_parent is deprecated and replaced by match_parent.

Answer (score 4):

match_parent, which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding).

wrap_content, which means that the view wants to be just big enough to enclose its content (plus padding)

For sake of better illustration, I have created a sample layout that demonstrate this concept. To see it's effect, I added a border of each textView content.

In "Match parent" textView content, we can see it's layout width spread out of it's parent whole length.

But we can see in "Wrap Content" textView content, it's layout width wrapped in of it's content(Wrap Content) length.

[image: Android Layout]

Comment: The question is about the difference between `match_parent` (which you covered) and `fill_parent` (which you didn't address). You instead compaed it to `wrap_content`, which the question doesn't ask about.

Answer (score 3):

To me **fill parent** and **match parent** performs the same function only that:

**fill parent**:
Was used before API 8

**match parent**
This was used from API 8+
**Function of Both**
Fills the parent view aside the padding

Answer (score 2):

FILL_PARENT was renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding) - Google

Answer (score 2):

`FILL_PARENT` is deprecated from the API level 8 and higher and it is renamed for the upper versions as `MATCH_PARENT`

Both are same `FILL_PARENT` and `MATCH_PARENT`,`FILL_PARENT` was used in the lower version less than API level 8 and MATCH_PATENT are used in higher API level greater than 8.

`FILL_PARENT` (renamed `MATCH_PARENT` in API Level 8 and higher), which means that the view wants to be as big as its parent (minus padding)

`fill_parent`: The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`.

For more details please visit [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) page

Answer (score 1):

Both, `FILL_PARENT` and `MATCH_PARENT` are the same properties. `FILL_PARENT` was deprecated in API level 8.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing (in API Level 8+). Use match_parent.

Both FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT are the same properties. FILL_PARENT was deprecated in API level 8.

Answer (score 0):

**1. match_parent**

When you set layout width and height as match_parent, it will occupy the complete area that the parent view has, i.e. it will be as big as the parent.

**Note** : If parent is applied a padding then that space would not be included.

When we create a layout.xml by default we have RelativeLayout as default parent View with android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_height="match_parent" i.e it occupies the complete width and height of the mobile screen.

Also note that padding is applied to all sides,

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Now lets add a sub-view LinearLayout and sets its layout_width="match_parent" and layout_height="match_parent", the graphical view would display something like this,

match_parent_example

Code

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.code2care.android.togglebuttonexample.MainActivity" >

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
android:background="#FFFFEE"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

**2. fill_parent :**

This is same as match_parent, fill_parent was depreciated in API level 8. So if you are using API level 8 or above you must avoid using fill_parent

Lets follow the same steps as we did for match_parent, just instead use fill_parent everywhere.

You would see that there is no difference in behaviour in both fill_parent and match parent.