# Is deprecated word the only difference between fill_parent and match_parent

Tags: android

I found that both `fill_parent` and `match_parent` means the same thing

- **fill_parent** means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.
- **match_parent** means that the view wants to be as big as its parent, minus the parent's padding, if any.

**The only difference that I found is that `fill_parent` is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`**

However, I didn't notice any difference between these two. If both are the same then, why is `fill_parent` deprecated. Can anyone explain any differences between these two except for the fact that one is deprecated and the other isn't?

I have gone through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Having two methods in the API which do the same thing is one reason to deprecate a method.

Comment: More on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As you said they are exact the same. As Romain Guy said, they have changed the name because `"fill_parent"` was confusing for developers. As matter of the fact, `"fill_parent"` does not fill the remaining space (for that you use the weight attribute) but it takes as much space as its layout parent. That's why the new name is `"match_parent"`.

Answer (score 9):

According to Romain Guy in [this](http://www.parleys.com/#sl=0&id=2191&st=5) video, these words mark the same behaviour. But many developers misunderstood what fill_parent meant, hence they came up with an alias.

Answer (score 7):

I have developed in Android long enough to also realize that there seems to be no difference except when you want to run on an older API. I would use `fill_parent` because I make all of my apps with minimum API 7. Also, on a side note, since Android is forward compatible this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to the existing answers. Here is a part of the source code from `LayoutParams` class, both FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT constants map to the same value. So we have absolutely the same functionality.

```
    public static class LayoutParams {
    /**
     * Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
     * FILL_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
     * minus the parent's padding, if any. This value is deprecated
     * starting in API Level 8 and replaced by {@link #MATCH_PARENT}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
    @Deprecated
    public static final int FILL_PARENT = -1;

    /**
     * Special value for the height or width requested by a View.
     * MATCH_PARENT means that the view wants to be as big as its parent,
     * minus the parent's padding, if any. Introduced in API Level 8.
     */
    public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
    ...
```