# Why did match_parent replace fill_parent?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>
> [What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android)
>
> [Is deprecated word the only difference between fill_parent and match_parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516825/is-deprecated-word-the-only-difference-between-fill-parent-and-match-parent)

`fill_parent` become deprecated. `match_parent` should be used instead. They are functionally equivalent, the only difference is name. What was wrong with `fill_parent`? I liked it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8516882/776244

Comment: This should be closed, as it is a duplicate. I'm surprised high rep users are answering this when @SamirMangroliya linked to the same question.

Comment: @kevlar1818: Assuming that's for me, if you see my answer was posted a minute before Samir's duplicated comment. Will vote to close.

Comment: @K-ballo Fair enough. Hope no harm is done, and glad we agree.

Answer (score 2):

What was wrong is that it does not *fill* the parent, but instead make it have the same dimension as the parent, or in other words *match* the parent dimension. The only case in which it does *fill* the parent is when the view is the single one in the layout.

Comment: @kevlar181: See the timings, _3 mins ago_ is before _2 mins ago_

Answer (score 0):

`match_parent` means that the child wants to be as big as the parent...maybe they wanted to make it sound more realistic?