# Fill remaining space: LinearLayout and weight or RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, layout

In case I have 2 views and I want one to take the necessary space and the other to take the remaining space, how should I go about it?

Let's suppose I want to lay the views vertically. The view below should take the necessary space (wrap_content) and the view above should take the remaining space of the container layout.

I've used these 2 solutions (simplified code):

1) `LinearLayout` with `weight`

```
<LinearLayout ...>
  <View height="0dp" weight="1" .../>
  <View height="wrap_content" .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

2) `RelativeLayout` with aligning

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
  <View height="wrap_content"    id="@+id/big" alignParentTop .../>
  <View height="wrap_content" below="@+id/big" alignParentBottom .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The`LinearLayout` approach always work, and the `RelativeLayout` usually works as expected but it is obviously ambiguous, since nothing says that the `@+id/big` view should be bigger than the one below.

I think the first approach is better, since is not ambiguous. However, I have seen many examples and answers with the second approach.

What solution do you use for these cases. Is there a best practice?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Taking [Touf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4749238/touf)'s answer, now I would do this (note the `match_parent`):

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
  <View height="match_parent"    id="@+id/big" alignParentTop .../>
  <View height="wrap_content" below="@+id/big" alignParentBottom .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use relative layout:

```
<View height="match_parent"    id="@+id/big" android:layout_above="@+id/view2" alignParentTop ... >

<View height="wrap_content" id="@+id/view2" alignParentBottom ...>
```

This way the first view will fill the screen height until it hits the 2nd view.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, although I don't know why android changed "fill_parent"  to "match_parent". I mean, your solution would be quite clear with the old size qualifier: "fill the parent as much as you can". The new size seems to say "match the parent size".

Comment: "fill_parent" and "match_parent" are the same. Check out these links:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854717/why-did-match-parent-replace-fill-parent
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

Comment: By the way, I guess I only need to use "above" or "below"; using both is redundant, isn't it? Maybe I should use below to reference the view that was declared before although I'm not sure whether I can use forward references (referencing views declared afterwards in the xml).

Comment: Yes I'm sorry no need for below="@+id/big", it is redundant, I forgot to remove it.

Comment: But how to set minHeight for firstview. I tried minHeight attribute but not working. The second view filled the screen completely (if its height is too large).