# Eclipse plugin to suggest replacements for deprecated feature warnings

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there anything I could install so that instead of getting deprecated feature warnings that just indicate something is deprecated and which only offer suppressing the warning I'd instead be given information about what the non-deprecated way to do something is.

ex instead of this Android code:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

getting this warning/suggestion:

```
The field ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is deprecated 
1 quick fix available: 
@ Add @SupressWarnings 'deprication' to 'currentMethod()'
```

I'd like to see:

```
The field ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT is deprecated 
1 quick fix available: 
@ Use LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT instead
```

instead of having to copy the message and search to find out what the [preferred fix is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516825/is-deprecated-word-the-only-difference-between-fill-parent-and-match-parent).

Comment: You are welcome to contribute other quick fixes to the Eclipse plugin, presumably.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I knew Android well enough to have definitive fixes I wouldn't be copy/pasting examples with the old way of doing things from random techblogs into eclipse in the first place.

Comment: Ah. I thought your concern was development speed.

Answer (score 2):

You are not going to find something like that. The migration actions are all different, implementing quick fixes takes quite a bit of work, and useful shelf life of such quick fixes would be rather short. Taking all of that into consideration, it just doesn't compute to develop these.

Comment: Is the default I'm seeing generated automatically (from metadata?) then?

Comment: By "the default", do you mean the quick fix to apply the @SuppressWarning annotation? That's supplied by JDT since it's a universal solution.