# Could not find "fill parent" in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am following an android tutorial and i need to do fill parent.

However, I didn't find it in the layout list. The only two options are "wrap content" and "match parent".

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 on MacBook Pro 2016.

Hope someone could help how to set it to fill parent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fill_parent has been deprecated, match_parent does the same thing now.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this link =>

[Is deprecated word the only difference between fill_parent and match_parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516825/is-deprecated-word-the-only-difference-between-fill-parent-and-match-parent)

fill_parent is deprecated and replaced by match_parent.