# How to attach MediaPlayer with SurfaceView in android?

Tags: android, media-player, surfaceview, surfaceholder

I'm building video player with android media player object. i'm able to hear the audio but the video does not appear on surfaceView. here is my code

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    String path;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean pausing = false;
    public static String filepath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.setFixedSize(176, 144);
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        try {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Uri fileuri = intent.getData();
            filepath=fileuri.getPath();
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(filepath);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

target is android 2.3 and above. how to fix it please help me..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

finally i fixed it myself. just called the `mp.setDisplay(holder);` inside the  surfaceCreated() function. and the final code is

```
public class PlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    String path;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private SurfaceView mPreview;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean pausing = false;
    public static String filepath;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        holder = mPreview.getHolder();
        holder.setFixedSize(800, 480);
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();


        try{
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            Uri fileuri = intent.getData();
            filepath=fileuri.getPath();
        }catch(Exception e){}


    }
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        mp.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.setDisplay(holder);
        play();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    void play(){
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(filepath);

            mp.prepare(); 

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not working for me throwing error illegal state exception in SurfaceCreated() method at line  mp.setDisplay(holder);

Answer (score 0):

> It is not working for me, throwing error illegal state exception in `surfaceCreated()` method at line `mp.setDisplay(holder);`

Declare `mp.setDisplay(holder)` as given below :

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) 
{  
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this,uri);
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
    mp.setDisplay(holder);
    mp.start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin user - You can use MediaPlayer with SurfaceView like following example. Just create `VideoLayout` class with following codes.

```
class VideoLayout(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?
) : FrameLayout(context, attrs), SurfaceTextureListener {

    private var isLoop: Boolean
    private var isSound: Boolean
    private var videoAlign: Int
    private var videoScale: Int
    private var mVideoWidth = 0f
    private var mVideoHeight = 0f
    private var fileName: String? = null
    private var fileFormat: FileFormat = FILE
    private var videoSurface: TextureView? = null
    private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

    enum class Scale {
        ORIGINAL, CROP, STRETCH, FIT_SCREEN
    }

    enum class FileFormat {
        FILE, URI, URL, OTHER
    }

    enum class Align {
        TOP, TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT, CENTER, CENTER_LEFT,
        CENTER_RIGHT, BOTTOM, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT
    }

    init {
        val styledAttributes = context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, R.styleable.VideoLayout, 0, 0
        )

        fileName = styledAttributes.getString(R.styleable.VideoLayout_path_or_url)
        videoScale = styledAttributes.getInteger(R.styleable.VideoLayout_scaleType, 3)
        videoAlign = styledAttributes.getInteger(R.styleable.VideoLayout_align, 4)
        isLoop = styledAttributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.VideoLayout_loop, true)
        isSound = styledAttributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.VideoLayout_sound, false)

        styledAttributes.recycle()

        fileName?.let {
            setupView()
            it.setFileFormat()

            if (videoScale != 2) {
                calculateVideoSize()
                surfaceSetup()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        videoSurface = TextureView(context)
        addView(videoSurface)
        videoSurface?.surfaceTextureListener = this
    }

    private fun String.setFileFormat() {
        fileFormat = if (contains("http://") || contains("https://")) {
            URL
        } else if (contains("content://")) {
            URI
        } else if(contains("file://")) {
            FILE
        } else {
            OTHER
        }
    }

    private fun calculateVideoSize() {
        try {
            val metaRetriever = MediaMetadataRetriever()
            fileName?.let {

                if (fileFormat != OTHER) {
                    when(fileFormat) {
                        FILE -> {
                            val fName = it.substringAfterLast('/')
                            val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fName
                            )
                            Timber.d("$fName file exists: ${file.exists()}")

                            val fd = FileInputStream(file).fd
                            metaRetriever.setDataSource(fd)
                        }
                        URI -> {
                            val uri = it.toUri()
                            metaRetriever.setDataSource(context, uri)
                        }
                        else -> metaRetriever.setDataSource(it, HashMap())
                    }
                } else {
                    val afd = context.assets.openFd(it)
                    metaRetriever.setDataSource(
                        afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length
                    )
                }
            }

            metaRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT)?.let {
                mVideoHeight = it.toFloat()
            }
            metaRetriever.extractMetadata(METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH)?.let {
                mVideoWidth = it.toFloat()
            }
            metaRetriever.release()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun updateTextureViewSize(viewWidth: Int, viewHeight: Int) {
        var scaleX = 1.0f
        var scaleY = 1.0f

        val viewWidthFloat = viewWidth.toFloat()
        val viewHeightFloat = viewHeight.toFloat()

        val viewWidthFactor = viewWidthFloat / viewHeightFloat
        val videoWidthFactor = mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight

        when (videoScale) {
            0 -> { //original
                scaleX = mVideoWidth / viewWidthFloat
                scaleY = mVideoHeight / viewHeightFloat
            }
            1 -> { // crop
                if (viewWidthFactor > videoWidthFactor) {
                    scaleY = ((viewWidthFloat / mVideoWidth) * mVideoHeight) / viewHeightFloat
                } else {
                    scaleX = ((viewHeightFloat / mVideoHeight) * mVideoWidth) / viewWidthFloat
                }
            }

            3 -> { // fit-screen
                if (viewWidthFactor > videoWidthFactor) {
                    scaleX = ((viewHeightFloat / mVideoHeight) * mVideoWidth) / viewWidthFloat
                } else {
                    scaleY = ((viewWidthFloat / mVideoWidth) * mVideoHeight) / viewHeightFloat
                }
            }
        }

        var pivotPointX = 0f
        var pivotPointY = 0f

        when (videoAlign) {
            0 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat / 2f
                pivotPointY = 0f
            }
            1 -> {
                pivotPointX = 0f
                pivotPointY = 0f
            }
            2 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat
                pivotPointY = 0f
            }
            3 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat / 2f
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat / 2f
            }
            4 -> {
                pivotPointX = 0f
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat / 2f
            }
            5 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat / 2f
            }
            6 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat / 2f
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat
            }
            7 -> {
                pivotPointX = 0f
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat
            }
            8 -> {
                pivotPointX = viewWidthFloat
                pivotPointY = viewHeightFloat
            }
        }

        val matrix = Matrix().apply {
            setScale(scaleX, scaleY, pivotPointX, pivotPointY)
        }

        videoSurface?.setTransform(matrix)
        videoSurface?.layoutParams = LayoutParams(viewWidth, viewHeight)
    }

    private fun surfaceSetup() {
        val screenHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels
        val screenWidth = resources.displayMetrics.widthPixels
        updateTextureViewSize(screenWidth, screenHeight)
    }

    private fun surfaceAvailableWorkers(surfaceTexture: SurfaceTexture) {
        val surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        try {
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer?.let { player ->
                fileName?.let {
                    if (fileFormat != OTHER) {
                        when(fileFormat) {
                            FILE -> {
                                val fName = it.substringAfterLast('/')
                                val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fName
                                )
                                Timber.d("$fName file exists: ${file.exists()}")

                                val fd = FileInputStream(file).fd
                                player.setDataSource(fd)
                            }
                            URI -> {
                                val uri = it.toUri()
                                player.setDataSource(context, uri)
                            }
                            else -> player.setDataSource(fileName)
                        }
                    } else {
                        val afd = context.assets.openFd(it)
                        player.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length)
                    }

                    if (!isSound) player.setVolume(0f, 0f)
                    player.setSurface(surface)
                    player.isLooping = isLoop
                    player.prepareAsync()
                    player.setOnPreparedListener { obj: MediaPlayer -> obj.start() }
                }
            }
        } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
        } catch (ignored: SecurityException) {
        } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
        } catch (ignored: IOException) {
        }
    }

    private fun changeVideo() {
        try {
            onDestroyVideoLayout()
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer?.let { player ->
                fileName?.let {
                    if (fileFormat != OTHER) {
                        when(fileFormat) {
                            FILE -> {
                                val fName = it.substringAfterLast('/')
                                val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(
                                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fName
                                )
                                Timber.d("$fName file exists: ${file.exists()}")

                                val fd = FileInputStream(file).fd
                                player.setDataSource(fd)
                            }
                            URI -> {
                                val uri = it.toUri()
                                player.setDataSource(context, uri)
                            }
                            else -> player.setDataSource(fileName)
                        }
                    } else {
                        val afd = context.assets.openFd(it)
                        player.setDataSource(afd.fileDescriptor, afd.startOffset, afd.length)
                    }

                    if (!isSound) player.setVolume(0f, 0f)
                    player.isLooping = isLoop
                    player.setSurface(Surface(videoSurface?.surfaceTexture))
                    player.prepareAsync()
                    player.setOnPreparedListener { obj: MediaPlayer -> obj.start() }
                }
            }
        } catch (ignored: IllegalArgumentException) {
        } catch (ignored: IOException) {
        } catch (ignored: IllegalStateException) {
        } catch (ignored: SecurityException) {
        }
    }

    override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
        surfaceAvailableWorkers(surface)
    }

    override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {}
    override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean = false
    override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {}

    fun onDestroyVideoLayout() {
        mediaPlayer?.let {
            try {
                it.stop()
                it.release()
                mediaPlayer = null
            } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun onResumeVideoLayout() {
        mediaPlayer?.let {
            if (!it.isPlaying) {
                try {
                    it.start()
                } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun onPauseVideoLayout() {
        mediaPlayer?.let {
            if (it.isPlaying) {
                try {
                    it.pause()
                } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setPathOrUrl(fileName: String) {
        this.fileName = fileName
        fileName.setFileFormat()

        if (videoSurface == null) {
            setupView()
        }

        if (videoScale != 2) {
            calculateVideoSize()
            surfaceSetup()
        }

        if (videoSurface != null) {
            changeVideo()
        }
    }

    fun setIsLoop(isLoop: Boolean) {
        this.isLoop = isLoop
    }

    fun setScale(scale: Scale) {
        videoScale = scale.ordinal
    }

    fun setAlign(align: Align) {
        videoAlign = align.ordinal
    }
}
```

Add following to your layout.xml

```
<com.your.package.VideoLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:loop="true"
    app:sound="false"
    app:scaleType="crop"
    app:align="center"/>
```

Also this supports video `scaleType` like `center_crop`, `fit_screen`, `stretch` and `original`.