# Android player raising exception prepare failed:status 0x1

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to play audio file from res/raw folder.
but getting the error
***prepare failed: status = 0x1***

My code:

```
package com.example.lvm;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button introAudio;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                introAudio=(Button)findViewById(R.id.introAudio);
                introAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                                String name = "greeting";
                                 mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                            mp.release();
                                        }

                                    });

                                try {
                                     mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.example.lvm/raw/"+name);
                                         mp.prepare();
                                         mp.start();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                        }
                });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                return true;
        }

}
```

Comment: I have same problem. However in my case I download the file and store it. File exists right before I call prepare, all other streams are closed. If I call prepare some time later it doesn't throw an exception. Don't know what's the problem but didn't find solution yet. 
Filename is just guid

Comment: As usual, as soon as I shared my comment I found a solution.
First of all, I checked logs in DDMS to see any additional information about error. I found that error right before exception `Failed to open file 'audio/2f32a5de.mp4'. (No such file or directory)`. After that I found that in one specific case I do not create full path correctly :)

Answer (score 4):

```
prepare failed:status 0x1
```

is occuring because of either file path is in error or incorrect directory or Url or Uri found.

Try following in your code.

```
 mediaplayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.lvm/raw/"+name)); 
 //do not add any extension to name, eg. `R.raw.your_raw_file`
```

Instead of

```
mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.example.lvm/raw/"+name);
```

Comment: I did. now there is no any exception raised but I cant hear the play.

Comment: make sure the file is not corrupt, plz try with another file. I don't see any problem now.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion, I had to modify my code , but ur suggestion worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

First, check the name of your file. It **cannot** contains capital letter and special characters. Remove that file, change name and copy it to environment again. Then use in Eclipse `Project => Clean` function (R.java should be regenerated). You can also try to use `mp.setDataSource("android.resource://com.example.lvm/raw/"+name);` instead of `mediaplayer.setDataSrouce(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.lvm/raw/"+name));` Remember that do not add any extension to name, eg. `R.raw.your_raw_file`

Answer (score 1):

It seems creating 31 prepared `MediaPlayer` is the maximum. When you are trying to create the 32th and invoked `prepare` will fail with this error.

If this is the case, how to fix this:

1. Invoke `release` on useless `MediaPlayer`;
2. Limit how many `MediaPlayer` you can create. For example if you are using a queue, try `ArrayBlockingQueue<T>`.
3. Catch the `IOException e`, check `"Prepare failed.: status=0x1".equals(e.getMessage())`, if so retry.

Comment: Well I meant 32nd. :P