# How to show video in full screen without stretching?

Tags: android, android-videoview, aspect-ratio

I have used video as Full Screen background in the frame layout. But video running in the background looks stretched.If i use aspect ratio, the video layout may be shrinked depends on the screen width / screen height. how to rectify this?

Comment: maintain aspect ration

Comment: set videoview height and width wrapcontent & xml layout background black color. its like fullscreen as well as not strecthed

Comment: i want to do something like this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/172346/1586730/BgcTZgRAJ62EpGr/output.gif)

Comment: For an example, see the video players in Grafika (https://github.com/google/grafika), particularly the use of AspectFrameLayout in PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java .  It uses a custom FrameLayout to alter the View size to maintain the proper aspect ratio.

Comment: This Might help you, Refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8830491/1542636