# Playing background video across all activities

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-video-player

Is there any way to play the same background video in all activities? (preferably not to restart when opening a new activity)

Some methods from here: [Integrating video file in android app as app background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830111/integrating-video-file-in-android-app-as-app-background) kinda works, but only in one activity. For example, if I go from my main activity into another, when I come back some elements from my `.xml` file fails to visible load. In fact, the buttons are still there if I press where they should be, it works, but they are not visible.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work, but you might be able to use Fragments instead of activities and leave the background video playing in the activity or base fragment.

Comment: My app already has a lot of activities so I wont re-done everything with fragments..I was just thinking to change the design of the app with that backgroud video. It's not a big issue if it is restarting everytime, but I don't know why some elements doesn't appear when I am switching activities...