# ScrollView inside FrameLayout layout margin's issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a very weird issue with a `FrameLayout` holding a `ScrollView`. My layout looks like the following:

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   <...
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

The issue that I have is with the: `layout_marginTop` attribute on the `ScrollView`tag. It doesn't apply the same way accross different devices. For instance, on a Nexus S (running ICS) it is interpreted correctly by adding some space at the of the screen, but on another (Galaxy S2 running Gingerbread) it creates space at the bottom of the screen rather than the top of screen.

Any idea?

Thanks!

**[EDIT]**

- It seems that the problem is common to all devices running an Android version lower than 3.0.
- Thanks for noticing those non-sense extra attributes, it appears they were here because that `FrameLayout` used to be wrapped inside `LinearLayout` before.

Comment: Layout can be tricky. FrameLayout doesn't have an 'orientation' attribute, and unless it's the child of a LinearLayout that layout_gravity attribute will also have no effect. I suggest using some solid background colours to see whats actually going on... I suspect it's not what you think.

Comment: @ReubenScratton It's actually the child of another `FrameLayout` (should have mentioned it). I removed all those extra attributes as you suggested. Will try using solid background colours to see what's going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using `android:paddingTop` on the `ScrollView`instead of `android:layout_marginTop`.

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_paddingTop="50dp">
      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="vertical">
     </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   <...
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

No use `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. This is no sense.

Try to use `android:paddingTop="50dp"` in FrameLayout instead of `android:layout_marginTop="50dp"` in ScrollView

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50dp">
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Aren't `fill_parent` and `match_parent`exactly the same thing? I removed all the extra attributes. Will try adding a paddingTop at the `FrameLayout`, thanks!

Comment: They are [identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

try `android:fillViewPort=true`