# ScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight() can't get the right value

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a ScrollView which child's height is 500px,this contain 2
button and the sum of height of them is 500px.but the value of
child.getHeight() is 788 not 500 I know ScrollView extends Framelayout,i replace the ScrollView with  Framelayout in the same scene and the value of child.getHeight() is 500.

Why is this happen?

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge and what i found on serch is, when you use scroll view the scroll view adds some **padding** inside its `child elements` for its *comfort*. but in case framelayout this not happens so you are getting these different values for scrollview and framelayout. as you can see `android:margin` not works for scrollview but works for framelayout.  you can see these two examples for understanding-
[margin issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359459/scrollview-inside-framelayout-layout-margins-issue)

[difference between padding and margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin)