# Is there a way to add a Horizontal Scroll bar on a layout with a tablelayout?

Tags: android, eclipse, horizontal-scrolling, android-sdk-2.3

I have an activity that may have info that exceeds the horizontal width of a activity, is there a way to add a horizontal scroll bar so user may scroll left and right as needed?

My activity_fuel.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:stretchColumns="0">

  <TableRow 
      android:id="@+id/TableRow01" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_address"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100px" >

    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView02" 
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/title_activity_phone"
        android:width="150px"
        android:textStyle="bold">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="@string/title_activity_distance"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="100px" >
    </TextView>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>  


</RelativeLayout>
```

I am fairly new to Android development and just trying to have this information look somewhat pleasant to the eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You shouldn't use pixels (*px*) to set sizes of your `View`s, rather use density independent pixels (*dp*) as it is better for supporting many different screen sizes/resolutions/pixel densities. Read more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

2) Close the `TextView` tag like this: `<TextView ... />` rather than `<TextView ...></TextView>`. It both does the same thing, it just seems weird to make a pair tag out of something that doesn't host anything in between the tags...

3) Layouts are usually useless if you put only one thing inside them. Here you have a `RelativeLayout` and in it only a `TableLayout`. You can remove the `RelativeLayout` and set all the dimensions to the `TableLayout`.

4) Don't use `fill_parent`, use `match_parent`, they do basically the same thing, but `fill_parent` has been deprecated since API 8. If you're targeting a lower API level, you could probably use `fill_parent`, but definitely don't use a mixture of both. [What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent-property-in-android)

5) To get to what you're actually asking about - you can wrap your `TableLayout` into a `HorizontalScrollView`. So basically replace the `RelativeLayout` with a `HorizontalScrollView`. Should do what you want.

Hope it helps. If something doesn't work or if you have further questions, don't be afraid to ask.

Comment: By the way thank you for the detailed answer, and all the extra info.  Great stuff.