# LinearLayout doesn't fill the parent

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, fill-parent

`LinearLayout` doesn't fill the parent. I need to fill all elements by width.

Here is a photo that is showing on the smartphone. But in Android Studio xml preview all is looking right.

[image: photo]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:hint="Сообщение" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:hint="Тема" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="дата"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="время"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Важность"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is this the layout of an Activity or is it included in another fragment / container ?

By the way, `fill_parent` is deprecated since API 8. Use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: It's a fragment layout. Other fragment's with linear layouts and fill_parent attribute working well.

Comment: Is your onCreateView of your fragment something like that ? `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);`

Comment: @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.reminder_add, container, false);
        return view;
    }

Comment: It's all code of SherlockFragment for now.

Comment: SherlockFragment is just a subclass of support Fragment. Check that the container is match_parent too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace fill_parent with match_parent everywhere. Beside that, you have to set match_parent for the fragment's container layout inside your activity's XML.

Comment: It was'n problem in fill_parent. I wrote wrap_content for frame layout and fill_parrent solve my problem. Thank you for the answer )

Comment: Thought so :) You should still use match_parent instead of fill_parent. According to [What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5761970/2964379) there actually is no difference between them beside the naming, but fill_parent is deprecated -- probably just to make people use the "less confusing" name "match parent".