# Getting rendering problems while using view in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am novice in android studio. When I am using new in android studio, I am getting rendering problems in preview.

Without view:

[image]

But when I use view I am getting rendering problem:

[image]

I am confused why is it happening. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `View` instead of `view` in xml :

```
<View 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Also use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` for height and width of views because `fill_parent` constant is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by `match_parent`.

For more information see this post:

[What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Comment: what's the difference between these two terms?

Comment: I was asking about view and View. Also why am I getting rendering problems?

Comment: @user3641971: `View` is a class in android api but `view` is not class available in android that's why you are getting rendering issue