# Difference between match-parent and fill-parrent

Tags: android, android-layout

For so long im trying to understand the difference between match-parent and fill-parrent can any please explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After API 8, FILL_PARENT was renamed as MATCH_PARENT.   So , both are one and the same.

Official doc :  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html[enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 2):

They are identical. It was a result of a name change by Google as `fill_parent` was misleading. See here: [What is the difference between match_parent and fill_parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. At least from an technical point of view.

The  google simply renamed it because it didn't reflect what it actually did - to fill it's parent view. Matching it's parent bounds is more appropriate.

I recommended to use the new one "match_parent" because the old one could be dropped by google at any time (although it is deprecated for a long time now).