# Couldn't load Main.axml in Xamarin Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, mono

This is the first time of using Xamarin.

I couldn't open Main.axml, in the content tab, in order to modify the application view.

I am able only to display it in source tab.

The error message is "The layout could not be loaded: The operation failed due to an internal error: com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.SessionParams.(Lcom/android...

Does anyone know how to fix it.

Thanks all for your help,

Comment: can you show the contents of Main.axml?

Comment: It is the default Iain, as below;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your Android SDK install is incomplete/corrupt/mis-matched.

If you run the Android SDK manager (or Android Studio), are any errors reported? Use the manager to update to SDK 24.3+

If you still have problems, post the entire log as a gist.github.com (or similar) so we can have a look at the entire trace from XS.

Also are you on Windows or OS-X?

```
Xamarin Studio
Version 5.9.4 (build 5)
Installation UUID: c9eca622-356f-4681-a1d2-069016cc404f
Runtime:
    Mono 4.0.2 ((detached/198235d)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Package version: 400020004
Xamarin.Android
Version: 5.1.4.8
Android SDK: /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86
    Supported Android versions:
        2.3   (API level 10)
        4.0.3 (API level 15)
        4.4   (API level 19)
Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: FYI: The AXML that Iain listed is correct and loads/displays properly in XS.

Comment: Thanks Robert,

Yes it seems there were some issues while installing Xamarin.

I had to uninstall it, and install all Android SKD, and other tools, before installing Xamarin, and everything is fixed now.

Thanks alot for your help,

Comment: Nice to hear, happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Think the format was just slightly off, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

steps to change:

1. Remove the semi colon at the end of `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`
2. change `xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to
   `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` - Think the removal of the 'http://' might just be the the formatting of StackOverflow comments
3. finally change `"fill_parent"` to `"match_parent"` in both the `layout_width` and `layout_height` little info on the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Comment: Sorry Iain, but it didn't work

Even when i leave Main.axml source code blank, the content tab stills gives me this error message.

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Yes, and it is still the same.

This is the current source file ;

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: if you remove the semicolon at the end of xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" does it work?