# Android button orientation vertical width 100%

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Yesterday I started with android programming. Now I want to create a simple layout. Here is an image:

[image]

How can I give the buttons a width of 100%? When I write

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

will the button no longer displayed. What is my mistake?

Here is the code again.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `button`s' `layout_width` property to `match_parent`:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

**PS:** `fill_parent` & `match_parent` are the same , but the `fill_parent` constant is deprecated starting from **API Level 8** and is now replaced by `match_parent`.

(Both constants resolve to `-1` eventually)

Answer (score 2):

use `match_parent` in `Button` width

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Before using `match_parent`, make sure parent layout must consist full width of screen, that means parent layout must have 'match_parent' for it's width

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Just use `match_parent` or `fill_parent`

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

OR

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Comment: whats the difference between this two properties?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent

Comment: and as @Sparta said fill_parent is deprecated,thats true