# Textview not resizing after dynamically adding text?

Tags: android, xml

Here is my XML. I'm adding the text dynamically and setting it as wrap_content in the XML, but afterwards the textview does not seem to be resizing based on the contained text. I'm using an expandable layout to expand on click from https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout.
I'm assuming one of the parent heights have been set wrong, but I've check pretty much all combinations and nothing seems to be helping. Setting the height as hardcoded (500dp) works perfectly fine. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cardviewTwitterMessages"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/expandableButton1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
                        android:onClick="expandableButton1"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Recent Tweets"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                    <com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/expandableLayout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/expandableButton1"
                        android:background="#fff"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        app:ael_duration="400"
                        app:ael_expanded="false"
                        app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
                        app:ael_orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:id="@+id/TwitterMessagesText"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:minLines="50"/>
                    </com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:tint="#fdfdfd" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: change  <android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
to < android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between match\_parent and fill\_parent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TextView is trying to **match the parent**.
Make it **wrap_content** instead

```
<TextView
    android:textColorLink="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/TwitterMessagesText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minLines="50"/>
```

Also, your ScrollView is trying to **wrap_content** while all the children down to the TextView try to **match_parent**. This means that the ScrollView is trying to wrap its children when those same children are trying to figure out their parent width (in a chain up to ScrollView).

When you set the width to 500dp on your TextView, all of the upward views inherit that same size (because of their match_parent width) thus working perfectly fine.
On your ScrollView, either **match_parent** or give it some width so its children adjust to it.

**@EDIT**

Also, as a matter of clean code, replace your **fill_parent** with **match_parent**.
fill_parent was deprecated and replaced with match_parent on API 8
[reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761960/what-is-the-difference-between-match-parent-and-fill-parent)

Comment: Tried as you suggested, it still refuses to do anything. Could the coordinatorlayout cause these problems?

Comment: Hardly. The coordinatorLayout works just fine. How do you populate the TextVIew? Through the adapter or through basic textView.setText("asd")?