# Is using fill_parent still a proper practice?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, deprecated

During my research on what's the difference between `match_parent` and `fill_parent`, I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5761970/3345644) that at the time of API 8 epoch Google just 'renamed' `fill_parent` to `match_parent` since the latter better describes the effect and made `fill_parent` deprecated.

What is silly to me, being official and solid IDE at least in code inspection part, after so many years Android Studio 2.3.3 still doesn't highlight usages of `fill_parent` as deprecated and not asking to change it to `match_parent`. It doesn't strike `fill_parent` through  in suggestion lists also.

So the question is should we ALWAYS use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` in  new code or using them interchangeably  is kind of established practice in Android development and this is the reason why Android Studio doesn't warn us about the deprecation of `fill_parent`?

Comment: "The question is why after so many years Android Studio 2.3.3 still doesn't highlight usages of fill_parent as deprecated and not asking to change it to match_parent?" -- questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are unsuitable for Stack Overflow. The only one who can answer the question definitively is Developer X, who is unlikely to see this question. Anyone else can only offer opinions.

Comment: @CommonsWare: You're right. I've made edits in attempt to pose a question more clearly.

Comment: THey're the same thing, they just renamed it.  Frankly I wouldn't care about it-  they're not going to remove it because it isn't worth the cost, and if they do, a 10 second control-R will fix it.  On the top thousand things to worry about when coding Android list, this rates around 995.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#FILL_PARENT

In the documentation, you can see that FILL_PARENT and MATCH_PARENT have the same value (-1) so it is the same thing only with a different name.

In this post http://www.randomlytyping.com/blog/2014/2/9/matchparent-vs-fillparent it's explained a lot like:

> **So why was MATCH_PARENT added?**
>
> The Android team found that developers were misinterpreting FILL_PARENT to mean that a View would fill the remaining space left in its parent. In fact, by specifying FILL_PARENT, the View is requesting to be as big as its parent.
>
> **Okay, I get how FILL_PARENT/MATCH_PARENT works. What does it matter if I use one or the other?**
>
> FILL_PARENT is deprecated. Being deprecated does not make it the Devil, but eventually it will go away. Your application is more future-proof using MATCH_PARENT. Why use the deprecated option when the current option behaves exactly the same?