# Android SDK ImageButton stretches when Gravity.Right

Tags: android, sdk, imagebutton, stretch, gravity

I have this code:

```
ImageButton call = new ImageButton(context);
call.setId(9001+result.index);
call.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_call);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams call_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
call.setLayoutParams(call_params);
```

It renders the button the way I want it, but when I do this:

```
ImageButton call = new ImageButton(context);
call.setId(9001+result.index);
call.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.small_call);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams call_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.RIGHT
);
call.setLayoutParams(call_params);
```

It stretches the image, messing up the aspect ratio, and makes it blurry/pixelated.

So what is the correct way to render the image as in the first code snippet, but place the button where the second code snippet puts it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try  call.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.

See also [layout_gravity in LinearLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783896/problem-with-layout-gravity-in-linear-layout).

This  is a tutorial: [A Visual Guide to Relative Layouts In Android](http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334).

Comment: Non of the comments or answers so far allow me to do what I want to do: Align each call button right, center each button vertically in it TableRow, while preventing the button from scaling up or stretching.  I looked at the example sited above, and after following it, my buttons weren't aligned right or vertically centered.