# LayoutParams gravity not working

Tags: android

I have a parent LinearLayout with MATCH_PARENT for width and height .I am trying to figure out setting  gravity and layout_gravity with java code.

```
LinearLayout l=new LinearLayout(this);
l.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
l.setLayoutParams(ll);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Now i am adding a Button to it using the following code :

```
LayoutParams llb=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
llb.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
b.setLayoutParams(llb);
```

Now if i add this Button to LinearLayout l and make it the content view

```
l.addView(b);
setContentView(l);
```

all things are working properly. The button shows up in the Center and on the right side.

But if i embed this Button in a LinearLayout and then add this LinearLayout to the outer Layout as below

```
LinearLayout l2=new LinearLayout(this);
        l2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll2=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        l2.setLayoutParams(ll2);
        l2.addView(b);
```

// add this to main layout .The button has the same LayoutParams as above.

```
l.addView(l2);
            setContentView(l);
```

the Button always appears on the left and this

```
  llb.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
```

does not seem to work.

kindly update why this is not working.

thanks

Comment: Try using `l2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`

Comment: i am interested to know why this is not working rather than a workaround. i know i can do through setGravity.

Comment: @shayanpourvatan  to place the button within the linearlayout that has width set to match_parent you dont need gravity you need layout_gravity since button width is wrap_content and setting gravity to button will have no effect .gravity for button is only to move the text within button boundary and not move the button within the layout.

Comment: Gravity on horizontal linear layout doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/q/4783896/2627680

Comment: @headsvk thanks .that is the real reason.